# Preference relations and the existence of extensions of functions representing them

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, self-learning

In a book I found the following question:

> Let $\succsim$ be a complete preference relation on a nonempty set $X$, and let $\varnothing \neq B \subseteq A \subseteq X$. If $u \in [0,1]^A$ represents $\succsim$ on $A$ and $v \in [0,1]^B$ represents $\succsim$ on $B$, then there exists an extension of $v$ that represents $\succsim$ on $A$.
>
> *True* or *false?*

The answer says that the statement is **false**, but I cannot really see a counterexample. Sure I am missing somebody, maybe about the very concept of extension of a function.

*Is there somebody who can enlighten me on why it is the case that the answer is false?*

Thank you for for your time.

Comment: How do you know that $X$ is finite?

Comment: Indeed, truly this is a tragic and shameful oversight, that makes me think that this question – as it is – should be deleted. But, true enough, considering I still don't really see why the statement is false when $X$ is uncountable, I will edit it accordingly in the hope to get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $X=A=[0,1]$, and let $\succsim$ be simply $\ge$; clearly identity function on $A$ represents $\succsim$ on $A$. Let $B=\left[0,\frac12\right]$, and let $v:B\to[0,1]:x\mapsto 2x$; $v$ represents $\succsim$ on $B$, but clearly $v$ cannot be extended to a representation of $\succsim$ on $A$.

Comment: As always, really thanks a lot!

Comment: @Kolmin: You’re welcome!